# Объявление динамического массива

Tags: массивы, c

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно объявить динамический массив. Как сделать, чтобы если, например, StartPoint занимает больше 15 символов, к нему добавлялось ещё 3-4 символа? Общий размер массива у меня 50. Как сделать, чтобы при переполнении добавлялось ещё 15 строк?

```
typedef struct
{
    char StartPoint[15];
    char StartTime[20];
    char EndPoint[15];
    char EndTime[20];
    char Type[14];
} rover;
int p = 0, razm = 50;
rover *dat = (rover*)malloc(sizeof(rover)*razm);
```

Comment: > к нему добавлялось ещё 3-4 символа  
> при переполнении добавлялось ещё 15 строк

Только вручную, с перевыделением памяти (`realloc()`, вроде, но я в си не так много смыслю) и через функции-обертки. Если такая потребность возникает часто, возможно, проще будет реализовать список, где не надо перевыделять память.

Answer (score 1):

[@masiv1488](/users/20163/masiv1488), да, `realloc()`. Учтите, что адрес начала массива может иззмениться.

Для реализации Вам нужно (по крайней мере) хранить 3 переменные. Адрес начала, текущий размер и выделеннная память.

Также понадобятся константы (или переменные, или функция) для начального размера и приращения.

Иногда удобно объединять часть из них в структуру, например:

```
 struct da {
    char *body;
    size_t capacity, length;
 }; // подобие C++ string
```

Кстати, для начального выделения памяти годится тот же `realloc` (подробности в `man`).

И не забывайте про завершающий 0 в конце строки.

Answer (score 0):

Если память выделять вручную, надо отказываться от фиксированного размера, и структуру честно переопределить как

```
typedef struct
{
    char* StartPoint;
    char* StartTime;
    char* EndPoint;
    char* EndTime;
    char* Type;
} rover;
```